# React doesn't get custom attribute with the e.target.getAttribute() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to process custom attributes in my changeHandler. Unfortunately, React doesn't recognize the custom "data-index" attribute.

All other standard attributes (such as name, label, etc.) are recognized.

What am I doing wrong?

My input field:

```
  <Input
    name="test"
    label="test 1"
    data-index="0"
    value={values.test}
    onChange={handleInput}
  />
```

My changeHandler (data-index is always null here):

```
  const handleInput = (e: any) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const dataIndex = e.target.getAttribute('data-index');
    setValues({
       ...
    });
  };
```

**UPDATE:**

I found out that e.target.attributes outputs the following.

```
NamedNodeMap {0: aria-invalid, 1: id, 2: name, 3: type, 4: class, 5: value, aria-invalid: aria-invalid, id: id, name: name, type: type, class: class, …}
0: aria-invalid
1: id
2: name
3: type
4: class
5: value
length: 6
```

My data-index attribute is not recognized at all. Why?

Comment: What happens if you change `data-index="0"` to `data-index="5"`. Does it work then? Just curious.

Comment: I have multiple inputs wie different values for data-index. I have also changed data-index to dataIndex or just data. Nothing works..

Comment: So `5` or anything that isn't falsy doesn't work either? Just making sure.

Comment: Right, doesn't work either :)

Comment: You got a codesandbox to play with... This is an interesting problem

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It's a bigger project with reusable components where I took the relevant parts as a question.

Comment: Input is custom component that you built?

Comment: @Prime Yup it's an custom component with {...rest} for all other attribues. I've updated my question and added the recognized attribues.

Comment: @Codehan25, I've updated my answer. Please check

Comment: can you show code of Input component? tested in codesandbox with simple input, your code works

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-matsumoto-m0plu?file=/src/Input.js the console.log outputs: rest {data-index: "3"}. So the data-index attribute is there..

Answer (score 1):

You can access them via `e.target.dataset`. But I recommend you to apply more React-like way.

```
<Input
    value={values.test}
    onChange={() => handleInput({ name, label, index: 0 })}
/>
```

```
const handleInput = ({ name, label, index }) => {
    setValues({
       ...
    });
};
```

Comment: But I really want to know why the `getAttribute` fails :) (but this is the right answer)

Comment: Interesting, but why do all other attributes (such as name, label, etc.) work and only data-index doesn't? For example e.target.getAttribute('name'); get's the name attributes value.

Comment: That depends on your need, and in this way, you can keep code consequent in style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React + Typescript, you can typecast the target element and then use the getAttribute property on it.

```js
const handleInput: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const dataIndex = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).getAttribute('data-index');
};
```